# PHP Why is my globals array empty in my extended class

Tags: php, arrays, global

I am having trouble getting a global array in my extended class. The array is populated by paramaters that are passed using the url.

I get my url then explode it. Then I set the first two parameters to a class and method. Then re-base my array keys so parameters start at 0.

For example:

```
class App
{
    protected $controller = '';
    protected $method = '';
    protected $param = [];

    public function init()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
            $url = explode('/', filter_var(trim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
        else
        {
            header('Location: /home');
        }

        if (file_exists(APP . '/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')) 
        {
            $this->controller = $url[0];
            unset($url[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (DEVELOPMENT == true) {
                var_dump($url);
            }
            else
            {
                header('Location: /home');
            }
        }

        require_once 'controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';

        $className = ucfirst($this->controller);
        $class = new $className;

        if (isset($url[1])) 
        {
            if (method_exists($className, $url[1])) 
            {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
                $methodName = $this->method;
                $class->$methodName();
            }
        }

         $GLOBALS['param'] = array_values($url);
    }

    public function view($view)
    {
        require_once VIEW . '/header.htm';
        require_once VIEW . '/' . $view . '.htm';
        require_once VIEW . '/footer.htm';
    }
}
```

So if my url is site/class/method/foo/bar and I dump $GLOBALS['param'] I get

```
array (size=2)
0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
1 => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

Which is good and what I want.

However if I do the same dump on my extended class.

```
class User extends App
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump($GLOBALS['param']);    
    }
}
```

My array is empty. Really what I am trying to do is be able to get parameters from the url in any controller class and use them. How can I do that?

Comment: You really need to use [dependency injection](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/779/dependency-injection) instead of a global

Comment: I knew that! I mean I knew I was doing it wrong using globals. However Im still learning and the dependency injection is still confusing to me. If it's not too much to ask would you mind post an example that is relevant to my situation? Sorry in advance I'm a very slow learner.

Comment: Where do you get `$url`?

Comment: I do this $url = explode('/', filter_var(trim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

Comment: Where? Not in the method you try it to use at least.

Comment: Ill post my full code. Sorry I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: How do you use the classes? You first have to call the `init` method before the variable will have anything in it (therefore it's pretty much useless to dump the variable in the constructor).

Comment: App  and init are instantiated and called in the index. Im attempting an mvc concept

Comment: Post the code. And just because you make an `App` instance, doesn't mean it will share it with `User`. `User` is a new class based on the `App` class. The class instances don't share information with each other. Therefore what you try to do is without any logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was way off. I fixed my problem by parsing the params to the method with call_user_func_array like so

```
class App
{
    protected $controller = 'home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function init()
    {
        $url = $this->parseUrl();
        if (file_exists(APP . '/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')) 
        {
            $this->controller = $url[0];
            unset($url[0]);
        }

        require_once APP . '/controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';

        $this->controller = new $this->controller;

        if (isset($url[1])) 
        {
            if (method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])) 
            {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }

        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

        // Parse params to method
        call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
    }

    public function parseUrl()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['url'])) 
        {
            return $url = explode('/', filter_var(trim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }

    public function view($view)
    {
        require_once VIEW . '/header.htm';
        require_once VIEW . '/' . $view . '.htm';
        require_once VIEW . '/footer.htm';
    }
}
```

Then I can get the params in my extended class

```
class User extends App
{

    public function index($var = '', $otherVar = '')
    {
        echo $var. $otherVar;
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->view('user-register');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->view('user-login');
    }
}
```